# Using str(sys.argv[1]) in request.get(url,params=data)

Tags: python, python-requests

Hi I am trying to use sys.argv in request.get(url,params=data) data list.

I am failing it
here is code i wrote

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
import requests
from xml.etree import ElementTree

vlan = str(sys.argv[1])

url = "https://xxxx.xxx.com/api/"

data = {
    'key':'LUFRPT1VN2RyMmsxN0ljYWs1cdsaf3251VBkZHFLdHM9MEdHY3ZqWlpFQkI0UU1KeWpyZkV2OW9nM2pkSUE3NEdlRVVGSklWVTgvcz0=',
    'type':'op',
    'cmd':'<show><arp><entry name="ethernet1/5.608"/></arp></show>'
   }

output = requests.get(url,params=data)
```

What i want to use is here

```
'cmd':'<show><arp><entry name="ethernet1/5.608"/></arp></show>'
```

I want to take usr argument from command line and use instead of 608

so When i call the script ./script 123

I want to use 123 as this

```
'cmd':'<show><arp><entry name="ethernet1/5.123"/></arp></show>'
```

I tried to use

```
cmd':'<show><arp><entry name="ethernet1/5.$vlan"/></arp></show>'
```

It did not work

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The feature you are looking for is called "string formatting". There are two variants, one uses the [`%` operator](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations) and the other uses the [`str.format` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format).

`%` operator:

```
'cmd':'<show><arp><entry name="ethernet1/5.%s"/></arp></show>'%(vlan)
```

`str.format()`:

```
'cmd':'<show><arp><entry name="ethernet1/5.{}"/></arp></show>'.format(vlan)
```

Comment: `'..name="{vlan}"..'.format(vlan=html.escape(sys.argv[1], quote=True))`